# WSGI : environ['QUERY_STRING'] parse something without a question mark?

Tags: python, apache, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, wsgi

Suppose the url is:

```
 domain.tld/test?abc
```

This is the script:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    a = environ['QUERY_STRING']

    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    yield a
```

the output is:

```
abc
```

but the question is.. can the "?" be changed with some other symbol ?

for example..

```
 domain.tld/test-abc
```

is this possible without resorting to mod_rewrite and etc.. ?

Answer (score 0):

If you were using a framework such as Bottle, you could write your route handler to match your request URL, something like:

```
import bottle
application=bottle.Bottle()
@application.get('/test-<a>')
def test(a):
    return a
```